# Xcode cannot find Bolts framework even there is

Tags: ios, xcode

I reopened a xCode project after 1 month.
I tried to compile, but I run into this error:

"linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)"

Please, see the image below:

[image]

It seems that Xcode is not able to find Bolts Framework even if it is inside the project directory. I tried to delete and re-add it but it didn't work. I checked also the Framework search path but it is correct.

Any suggestion?
Thanks in advance

Comment: Where's the image? can you paste in the compiler output?

Comment: @Shai Sorry for the error! I've just edit the post.

Comment: add other linker flags -ObjC

Answer (score 3):

If you already have `-ObjC` linked, verify if Bolts is included in your Link Binary with Libraries section of the Build Phases. If it is, try to remove the frameworks from the project and re-adding them, download the frameworks again, but without copying it to your project folder.

If it still doesn't work, try using CocoaPods in your project and add this to your Podfile:

```
pod 'Bolts'
```

Comment: where I can find if -ObjC is linked?

Comment: On your Project, go to your target, then Build Settings, and search for "Other Linker Flags"