# Module Bolts not found

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, parse-platform, cocoapods

[image]

I have xcode version 12.0.1 and version 10.15.7 macOS on my macbook

I keep getting this error, no matter how many times I restart my laptop, xcode, pod deintegrate and pod install, and have cleaned derived data multiple times, to no avail

Please help!

Comment: This is from a few years ago, but maybe it helps: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27635966/xcode-cannot-find-bolts-framework-even-there-is

Comment: tried that ^^, didn't help :'(

Comment: Try building to prime the Xcode module cache.

Comment: ^^ what?? kindly elaborate on what you mentioned @Paul. I have cleaned and built multiple times

Comment: In Xcode Product->Build

Comment: yes I have tried that already @Paul, didn't work

Comment: I have the same issue. I hope a pod update is coming soon.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This Issue is related to Parse end. I just got a description from Parse team to fix this and they recommended to use Xcode 11, They accepted that they have an issue with Xcode 12. they are working on it and will update once got this fixed. Reference Screenshot is attached. [image]

Answer (score 1):

Did you see if during your pod install the logs specifically said Bolts was installed?
It should be by default, but it could be missing due to some reason (that would be specified in the logs).
Just to be double-sure, also check if your Cocoapods is in the latest version (1.9.3 as I write this answer).

And last but not least, you can integrate it manually if you need to:
https://www.back4app.com/docs/ios/manual-integration

But again, Cocoapods usually would integrate that for you.

Comment: thanks! and yes, I saw that Bolts was installed as well. I am actually not using any frameworks, since I am using objective-c, not swift. This is what the output was upon pod install: 
Downloading dependencies
Installing AFNetworking (3.2.1)
Installing AMPopTip (1.5.3)
Installing Bolts (1.9.1)
...other pods...

Comment: is cocoa pods version supposed to be 1.9.3 or the Bolts version? cuz my Bolts version is 1.9.1 @Alexander